# Hot Smoked Salmon on Big Green Egg

Tags: salmon, smoking

What is the best process/technique to use for hot smoking salmon on a smoker like the [Big Green Egg](http://www.biggreenegg.com/)?

Comment: I would like to see this tagged with biggreenegg.

Comment: Hello JPrescottSanders. Your question looks good to me and I hope you get good answers, but - given the FAQ - you'll not get recipes. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Welcome to the site @JPrescottSanders.  As @Tobiasopdenbrouw has stated we do not allow recipe requests on this site.  I have edited your question to remove this part, there is a discussion about this [here](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic).

Comment: I appreciate the info on the "No recipes" stance and thinking about it sort of agree with how recipes might make finding good technical information sort of crunchy.  Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks for adding the big-green-egg tag, I could see that being a popular one.

Comment: oops.  removed the `big-green-egg` tag.  I think this is too specific and I think the `smoking` tag should cover it.  I could *maybe* see a `smoker` tag for the equipment, but I think `smoking` probably covers it.  Perhaps a meta discussion to see what the community think...

Comment: I think a meta discussion may be warranted as cooking in the big-green-egg may require some additional information.  Some responses to this question may be more generic, and might apply to all smoking equipment, but I would also like to see if there are any egg heads in the forum that might have some specific advice.  I guess we'll see where the answers take us.  if we get some BGE specific answers then that might be a sign as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy:

- Soak wood chunks or chips over night in water.
- Start hard lump charcoal in BGE (or any smoker)
- Scatter wood over the coals
- Let salmon sit out for 15 - 20 mins to come to room temp
- Get  BGE smoking and adjust temperature to 180F to 200F
- Put salmon on grill
- Smoke till finished. About 35-45 mins for 1 1/2 lbs fillet. It wants to be cooked through and flakey.

I'll often do this while smoking a Boston Butt, which is an all day affair. If I've got room, I throw a salmon fillet on in the middle of the day for lunch.

If you're just getting in to smoking with the BGE, I highly recommend the book [Smoke and Spice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/155832061X).

Comment: I'll have to check that book out.

Answer (score 1):

I get good results smoking salmon on the Big Green Egg at 150-180'F (200 is too high), with indirect heat.  Smoke for AT LEAST 6 hours spraying every hour with apple juice.